# How can I integrate chess.js and chessboard.js?

Tags: javascript, html, chess, chessboard.js

I am trying to integrate [Chess.js](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js) and [Chessboard.js](http://chessboardjs.com/) but I am having some problems along the process. I have downloaded successfully `Chessboard.js`, unzipped the folder and within it I created a file called `index.html` that looks like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chess Match</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chessboard-0.3.0.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chessboard-0.3.0.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="board" style="width: 400px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var board = ChessBoard('board');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This proves that the library is working properly. Now I would like to integrate the `Chess.js` library in order to play a random match as described in [this integration page](http://chessboardjs.com/examples#5001).

How can I do that?

First I need to install Chess.js so I download the repo and I put the `chess.js` and `chess.min.js` files inside the `js` folder, but I am not sure of how should I proceed from here. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You're not actually calling the `chess.js` file

Comment: The example you linked to had some code. Did you try copying that into your file?

Comment: Multiple scripts are loaded in the oder you put `<script src"..` tags and their code can use code from previously loaded scripts. Just load the libraries first, then have your code 3rd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 
`<script src="js/chess.js"></script>` into your file.

Comment: Yeah, that was easy, but how can I integrate the code for making random moves then?

Comment: Ok, I solved it. I was placing that too of course, but I was calling the script for making a move from the wrong location.