# Check for Checkmate in Chessboard.js

Tags: javascript, chess, chessboard.js

I making a chess game with chessboardjs and I want to check for checkmate.

How can I do this ?

I'm using that code but it isn't working.

```
if (game.game_over() == true) {
    alert("Game Over");
}
```

The whole function is:

```
var onDragStart = function (source, piece, position, orientation) {
    if (game.game_over() == true) {
        alert("Game Over");
    }
    if (turn == 1) {
        if (piece.search(/^b/) === -1) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (piece.search(/^w/) === -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (turn == 1) {
        turn = 0;
    } else {
        turn = 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: If game.game_over() returns a boolean, you do not need to compare it to a true value. Just use the returned boolean as the if check.

Comment: Beyond that, could you post the game.game_over() function so we can see what it's logic is and why it might not be returning as true/false?

Comment: @TimHunter     
<code>
game_over: function() {
      return (
        half_moves >= 100 ||
        in_checkmate() ||
        in_stalemate() ||
        insufficient_material() ||
        in_threefold_repetition()
      );
    },
</code>

Comment: Hmm, I'm assuming these other functions are part of the already built chessboard.js system and are thus assumed to be working as intended? You should be able to use that `in_checkmate()` function to get what you're looking for if you're looking for the checkmate condition specifically.

Comment: How is it not working?  Are you getting errors in your console?

Comment: @Amy I don't get any errors but when achieve checkmate the function is not return true so the alert is not working.

Answer (score 1):

To check the state of a chess position, you'll need more than the chessboard representation but also a chess *engine* (the program which understands/enforces chess *rules*). A favorite for javascript is: `chess.js` (`chessboard.js` is *only* a graphical representation of the board and doesn't include any of the logic required to check for possible moves etc)

Like in this question [How can I integrate chess.js and chessboard.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351308/how-can-i-integrate-chess-js-and-chessboard-js)

These libraries are often used together: https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/

and from there you have access to the rules of chess: https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/#game_over

Answer (score 0):

To determine a game has ended, you have to calculate the possible legal moves for the side to move.
No legal moves for the side to move implies the game has ended.
If there are no legal moves and the king of the side to move is in check => checkmate.
Otherwise it is stalemate.